Find global extremums of function
We have $\left\{\begin{matrix}
xyz \rightarrow extr\\
\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}z^2=1 \\
x+y+z=0\end{matrix}\right.$
Let's find Lagrange Multipliers: $L = \lambda_0(xyz) + \lambda_1(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}z^2-1)+\lambda_2(x+y+z)$, then
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \lambda_0yz + \lambda_1x +\lambda_2$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \lambda_0xz + \lambda_1y +\lambda_2$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = \lambda_0xy + \lambda_1z +\lambda_2$
Let $\lambda_2 = 0$, then   :$\left\{\begin{matrix}
yz+x\lambda_1=0 \\
xz+y\lambda_1=0\\
xy+z\lambda_1=0\\ \end{matrix}\right.$
I've tried: $yz+x\lambda_1 - xz-y\lambda_1 = 0 \Rightarrow z = \lambda_1$ and so on, I got: $x=y=z=\lambda_1$.
But then according to $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}z^2=1$ and
$x+y+z=0$
We have $\frac{3}{2}\lambda_1^2 = 1$ and $3\lambda_1 = 0$.
Please, help me where I am mistaken???

Why is $\lambda_0$ here?

As commented by @YvesDaoust and @NN2, there are two mistakes: letting $\lambda_2=0$, and not letting $\lambda_0=1$. The method of Lagrange multipliers results in
$$\exists a,b\in\Bbb R\quad\begin{cases}yz&=ax+b\\zx&=ay+b\\xy&=az+b\end{cases}$$
which implies
$$0=\begin{vmatrix}yz&x&1\\zx&y&1\\xy&z&1\end{vmatrix}=(x-y)(y-z)(x-z).$$
Up to permutation, $y=x$, and $(x,z)$ must then be chosen such that $2x^2+z^2=2$ and $2x+z=0$, i.e. $z=-2x$ and $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$. The values of the extrema (minimum and maximum) of $xyz$ are therefore
$$extr=\pm\frac2{3\sqrt3}.$$
Another method is to notice that the two constraints are equivalent to:
$$x+y+z=0,\quad xy+yz+zx=-1.$$
We are therefore looking for the extremum values of $e$ such that the equation
$$t^3-0t^2+(-1)t-e=0$$
has three (not necessarily distinct) real roots. Letting $f(t):=t^3-t$, $f'(t)=3t^2-1=0\iff t=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$, so these extremum values of $e$ are
$$extr=f\left(\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=\mp\frac2{3\sqrt3}.$$


I've also added, just during your editing, a solution which avoid Lagrange's multipliers! It seems nicer and more effective in this simple case.

As an alternative since $z=-x-y$ we have
$$f(x,y,z)=xyz =g(x,y)=-x^2y-xy^2=-y^3\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac xy\right) \tag 1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}z^2=1 \iff x^2+xy+y^2=1 \iff y^2\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac xy+1\right)=1 \tag 2$$
Note that constraint $(2)$ is an ellipse such that $y\in \left[-\frac2{\sqrt 3},\frac2{\sqrt 3}\right]$.
Now, from $(2)$ we obtain
$$y^2\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac xy\right)=1-y^2$$
and plugging in $(1)$ we have
$$g(x,y)=h(y)=-y+y^3$$
which has extrema $\pm \frac2{3\sqrt 3}$ at $y=-\frac1{\sqrt 3},\frac1{\sqrt 3}$ and at the boundaries $y=-\frac2{\sqrt 3},\frac2{\sqrt 3}$


Fine, but how do we restrict the domain of $h$, to justify that the extrema are global?

@AnneBauval From here $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}z^2=1$ and $x+y+z=0$ which is an intersection sphere-plane. I add that.

That is the ellipse $x^2+xy+y^2=1$.

Yes but how do we, instead, keep track in your calculation that the domains are restricted, and to which intervals? In particular, what is your domain of $h$?

@AnneBauval When we put together the constraints we need to specify it.

$\min(t^2+t+1)=\frac34$ so by (2), your domain of $h$ is $[-2/\sqrt3,2/\sqrt3]$.

I'm adding this part.

@AnneBauval Thanks to have pointed out this issue, indeed in this way the solution is no so effective by this method.

Here is an alternative solution if you are familiar with cubic equations and its discriminant.
Let $p := x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$. Then $p = 0$ and $q = -1$ (using $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = p^2 - 2q$).
Thus, $x, y, z$ are the three real roots of the cubic equation $u^3 - u - r = 0$.
This is a depressed cubic. Its discriminant is given by $\Delta = -27r^2 + 4$.
Since the cubic has three real roots, its discriminant is non-negative, i.e. $-27r^2 + 4 \ge 0$ which results in $-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}} \le r\le \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$.
When $r = \pm\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$, the discriminant is zero and thus two of $x, y, z$ are equal.
Letting $x = y$, we have $y + y + z = 0$ and
$yy + yz + zy = -1$ which results in $z = -2y$ and $-3y^2 = -1$. Thus, $y = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
We have $r = \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$
when $x = y = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $z = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.
We have $r = -\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$
when $x = y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $z = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.
(Note:
The discriminant of the depressed cubic $u^3 + au + b$ is given by $-4a^3 - 27b^2$. Also, this discriminant is equal to $(u_1 - u_2)^2(u_2 - u_3)^2(u_3-u_1)^2$ where $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are the three roots (not necessarily real) of the cubic.)
